# which compiler to use for porting C++ through ndk?

Tags: java, android, visual-c++, android-ndk, porting

I've an android app that does dome image proceesing. i'd like to write certain parts of the app in C++ for performance reason, then call these methods through the NDK. do i need a specific C++ compiler eg for embedded systems or will any do? Has anyone a link to the correct download for the compiler? thanks matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android NDK comes with a compiler included, which is a version of GCC. You should not need to install any other.

Switching from Visual Studio to Eclipse will make your Android development life much easier, though. All the convenient tools are Eclipse-based.

Comment: hi, ok thanks. I currently use Eclipse with the Android plugin, that's what i've developed the app in. So i can write C++ code straight away and compile in eclipse?

Comment: Oh, on Windows you'll need Cygwin, it seems. I don't remember if you need to invoke `ndk-build` manually, or whether Eclipse does that for you. Just read some tutorials, it should clear things up.

Comment: ndk-build can be invoked from Eclipse by installing the Eclipse Sequoyah plugins for Android (eclipse.org/Sequoyah). Similar code was recently contributed to the AOSP by the Eclipse CDT lead, but it hasn't been approved yet. It's a huge patch and I think the Android tools team is waiting for ADT12 to ship before integrating and testing the patch.  If you check back with the tools project (tools.android.com) periodically, you will get some more information. For now, if you want to build from eclipse, use Sequoyah.  (Disclaimer, I'm the Sequoyah project lead)